# Reaching an aliased website in a virtual machine on windows

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-player

I'm running windows 10 with a virtual machine (vmware, running ubuntu) wherein the vmware is running a server on port 80. The issue is I have to test out various arrangements of subdomains (ie `test.website.com`). I have tried to change the windows `/etc/hosts` to redirect properly (`192.168.127.***    test.website.com` where the IP address is obtained from vmware using `hostname -I` - done with NAT configuration; also tried `127.0.0.1` with bridged setting - always followed by a call to `ipconfig /flushdns`), but this doesn't seem to connect to the server running on port 80 within the VM. The existence and the relaying of the url to the server is key in order to discern the proper response. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is typically the host PC. Assuming the VM is accessible from the host via its IP, you would likely want to use the IP of the VM instead.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I tried the vmware address as well, (192.168.127.***), but this did not work.

Comment: Then there is likely another configuration issues. As a suggestion, the simplest solution would probably be to make the adapter for your VM bridged (i.e. have the VM use the physical adapter of the host PC). The first three octets of the VM should match the first three octets of your hosts IP (i.e. both should have e.g. 192.168.127.xxx addresses). You could try something with Port Forwarding/NAT but that would be a bit more involved.